# SQL Server date math with float (like sysdate + 1.4793625 days in Oracle)

Tags: sql-server

Converting a db from Oracle to SQL Server.  I need something similar to what Oracle lets me do with dates:

```
... WHERE tbl.date_col < sysdate - 1.234
```

where the float represents a fractional number of days (the float value will be passed in).

DATEADD only accepts integers for the second argument, so that won't work.  It seems kind of hacky to do some math ahead of time and then have

```
DATEADD(year, ?, DATEADD(month, ?, DATEADD(day, ?, DATEADD(hour, ?, 
  DATEADD(well, you get the picture)))))
```

Please tell me there's a more elegant and readable solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server is moving away from this capability entirely. For example, you can say:

```
SELECT GETDATE() + 1;
```

But you can no longer do this with the newer date/time types, e.g.:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) + 1;
```

Yields:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

So I strongly recommend stop using `FLOAT` and shorthand date math for this. If you are trying to subtract some fractional number of days, convert it to the most important granularity first, and then use `DATEADD` with that granularity. e.g. the following works just fine:

```
WHERE tbl.date_col < DATEADD(SECOND, 86400*-1.234, GETDATE());
```

Comment: Yeah, the docs on the difference between datetime and datetime2 (for example) on why some implicit conversions etc. aren't allowed aren't super-satisfying to me, but I'm a huge fan of not fighting the system (as that can cause more problems than it solves).  Thanks for the answer